# Why my fitted genextreme distribution have no mean/variance?

Tags: scipy, statistics

I have the following code for estimating a generalized extreme value distribution from scipy.

```
from scipy.stats import genextreme
ys = [22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 22.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 29.9, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 26.6, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.9, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764, 22.058823529411764]
shape, loc, scale = genextreme.fit(ys)
mean, var = genextreme.stats(shape, loc, scale, moments='mv')
```

I got the following fitted parameters (shape, location and scale respecitvely):

```
-2.787020488783334
22.058823529411782
5.0707584099150134e-14
```

Thus, the shape is negative but the documentation on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html allows the shape to go negative.

However, my mean and variance are both `nan`.

It looks like I can fit a model, and the fitted parameters look reasonable, but why am I unable to get a mean from the fitted distribution?

Answer (score 1):

When the shape parameter is less than -1, the distribution is sufficiently "fat-tailed" that the mean and variance don't exist.  This is noted in the table on the right side of the [wikipedia article on the generalized extreme value distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution)--but note that the sign of the shape parameter `c` used by [genextreme](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html) is the opposite of the parameter ξ in the wikipedia article.